# Jabber client issue with Authentication c#

Tags: c#, xmpp, chat, publish-subscribe

Given below is a sample console application uses jabber-net client for sending a sample test message after authenticating the connection.
I am receiving error while authenticating the login request.Error is given below.

**"Unable to read data from the transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. "**

I am new into this XMPP. So many projects available online but none of them found relevent.
Please provide with your valuable information or links that can be useful for developing a free jabber client library for my application.

Sample code is attached below!

```
class Program
{
    // we will wait on this event until we're done sending
    static ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    // if true, output protocol trace to stdout
    const bool VERBOSE = true;
    const string TARGET = "sample@example.com";


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JabberClient j = new JabberClient();
        j.User = "sample@jabber.org";
        j.Server = "jabber.org"; // use gmail.com for GoogleTalk
        j.Password = "samplePassword";


        // don't do extra stuff, please.
        j.AutoPresence = false;
        j.AutoRoster = false;
        j.AutoReconnect = 30;

        // listen for errors.  Always do this!
        j.OnError += new bedrock.ExceptionHandler(j_OnError);

        // what to do when login completes
        j.OnAuthenticate += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(j_OnAuthenticate);

        // listen for XMPP wire protocol
        if (VERBOSE)
        {
           // j.OnLoginRequired += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(j_OnLoginRequired);
            j.OnReadText += new bedrock.TextHandler(j_OnReadText);
            j.OnWriteText += new bedrock.TextHandler(j_OnWriteText);
        }

        // Set everything in motion
        j.Connect();

        // wait until sending a message is complete
        done.WaitOne();

        // logout cleanly
        j.Close();
    }

    static void j_OnWriteText(object sender, string txt)
    {
        if (txt == " ") return;  // ignore keep-alive spaces
        Console.WriteLine("SEND: " + txt);
    }

    static void j_OnReadText(object sender, string txt)
    {
        if (txt == " ") return;  // ignore keep-alive spaces
        Console.WriteLine("RECV: " + txt);
    }

    static void j_OnAuthenticate(object sender)
    {
        // Sender is always the JabberClient.
        JabberClient j = (JabberClient)sender;
        j.Message(TARGET, "test");

        // Finished sending.  Shut down.
        done.Set();
    }

    static void j_OnError(object sender, Exception ex)
    {
        // There was an error!
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString());

        // Shut down.
        done.Set();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example you use **sample@jabber.org** as username. This is the complete bare Jid. The username (node part) in xmpp is the part before the "@" only. So try to use **sample** as username instead of **sample@jabber.org**.

```
j.User = "sample";
j.Server = "jabber.org";
j.Password = "secret";
```

Comment: i did the same like you said.. Still i am receiving the same error.
**"Unable to read data from the transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately."**
I think the issue is with the port that is using.

Comment: if i specify the port. i am receiving the following error.

**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 208.68.163.220:420**

Comment: then please attach your Xml debug output to your question. Then we ca see if it gets a connection at all, and where it stops.

Comment: SEND:<stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="85af7ea
f" xmlns="jabber:client" to="talk.google.com" version="1.0">
RECV: <stream:stream from="talk.google.com" id="6FD09146E87A4A80" version="1.0"
xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
RECV:"<stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><requir
ed/></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X
-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:fe
atures>

Comment: <stream:error><host-unknown xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"/>
<str:text xmlns:str="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams">Set the 'to' attribute
 of stream element to the domain part of the user's JID. Example: to='gmail.com'
.</str:text></stream:error></stream:stream>
SEND: <iq id="JN_1" type="get"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:auth"><username>physiaapp
</username></query></iq>

Comment: you have talk.google.com in the Server property, it must be gmail.com or whatever comes after the @ in your google ID when using google apps

Comment: thanks.. still having issues, related to the port.
**  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 208.68.163.220:5222**

It would be nice if you try out my sample code and check if the issue persists.

Comment: have you enabled SRV resolving in jabber.net? I think 208.68.163.220 is not the correct ip address for jabber.org

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29180/discussion-between-cslijo-and-alex)

Comment: can you please have a look on the below question pls..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293173/pubsub-example-using-jabber-protocol-in-c-sharp